# .NET 8 Blazor Interactive WebAssembly HttpClient and Identity issues

Tags: .net, blazor, asp.net-identity, blazor-webassembly, dotnet-httpclient

This is how I created the project

[image: Solution creation]

So far I have:

- Added Roles to the project, and they are working on FE and BE, e.g. I have added a specific user to a role, and content is rendered on the FE if the user has a role, and the BE endpoint can be accessed directly if the user has role = request is sent by the browser and this is OK.

My problem is HttpClient or HttpClientFactory registration, what I have done so far:

- I have added Controllers to the BE project
- I have added HttpClient service registration (but this time it has to be added to BE - due to interactivity...)

My next step is to use a generic solution for HTTP communication e.g. in my case I have written my own, but let's take refit as an example, how do I register refit and use it in FE?

The problem is, on the client side, you can't just register it as before due to the interactivity since it has to be on BE

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("WebAPI", client =>
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress)
```

Now what? My scenario is very complex, and this is what I want to achieve:

- I want to have BE API
- I want to have FE WebAssembly
- I want to have a new Identity implementation that is written in Razor components
- I want to have Generic HttpClient implementation with HttpClientFactory on FE in order to access data from BE
- I want to preserve authentication and authorization and let users access only parts for which they have Roles, but this has to be included in the HttpClient too
- Later on, I want to add more applications e.g. .NET MAUI to consume my existing API.

In the end, I did read a lot about render modes and everything else, and I find it very hard to achieve my goal with the current mindset, any suggestions and concrete answers will be very appreciated.

Comment: You say *I have added HttpClient service registration (but this time it has to be added to BE - due to interactivity...)* Well, the HttpClient is at the FE, you use it to make calls to your BE. An httpclient at BE would be used to call external services. Where exactly is your `HttpClient` then?

Comment: @WiktorZychla It has be registered in the BE due to interactivity of WebAssembly - you can create a project as per picture provided and see it your self, only way to make it work is that way - it is also part of Microsoft documentation.

Comment: Hmm, created a Blazor 8 solution with your settings. Added `Microsoft.Extensions.Http` to the Blazor Webassembly client project. Registered the `HttpClient` at the FE with the `AddHttpClient`. Made a server request from the client. This works. What am I missing?

Comment: That’s not possible with web assembly interactivity - e.g. if you inject http client in a component and you want to trigger request within on initialised method, it won’t work - since it requires HttpClient to be added, and due to the web assembly interactivity - HttpClient has to be added to the backend. It seems that only solution is to turn off interactivity and than there are other problems to solve such us SSR - I don’t want this. I want to have same as in .NET 7 - blazor web assembly hosted application with HttpClient + role based identity authentication.

Comment: Your injection could just be the service provider and your service has some logic to determine where it is being registered...

Comment: Here is the project - https://github.com/JasminSAB/BlazorApp1

Comment: Took a short look, seems that indeed, you can't make a httpclient call from within the oninitialized but it works - of course - when called from a late event (e.g. a button click). I wonder if there's a simple workaround over this.

Comment: I've looked into it. It's not that you can't make a http client call but rather, the httpclient.BaseAddress is empty in OnInitialized (and it's not empty if called e.g. from a button click). A quick workaround was to use `var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, Navigator.BaseUri + "api/test");` with `@inject NavigationManager Navigator`. The navigator correctly returns the baseuri even in oninitialized and the httpclient succeeds. Could this be a workaround you look for?

Comment: Thank you for going deeper, this is also what I tested based on your inputs. This is not good, what I am thinking to try is the template that is not global and it is per component / page - I think that way I can reach my goal = to have HttpClient in OnInisilized methods, thing is, currently I can’t get data on init - and as you know, this is the first step you want to do - display data to the user.

Comment: Here is a new GitHub repository - https://github.com/JasminSAB/ObojeIntraktivity, in this case, I have created a project with both interactivities the server and web assembly and per component, the trick, in this case, is that you need to implement the same service on both sides, on the client and server to cover interactivity. 

In case of a client call it uses the HttpClient, and I have created CookiHandler to pass the auth state to the server.

My plan is in the next iteration to create a project for only web assembly interactivity...

Comment: Sadly, this scenario is poorly covered in the docs. I haven't found a single reliable and exhaustive source of how we are supposed to architecture this. On the other hand, as you said, this is a basic scenario, something so common that it should be covered in basic tutorials. Drop an answer here when you find a way you consider reasonable.